# Evil man uses robot teddy bear to raise a boy to be a killer

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, robots

An evil man wants to hire an assassin. He cannot find anyone who can do the job. For many years every human child has been raised with a talking robot teddy bear.

Amongst many other things these teddy bears do is to condition the child to be incapable of murder.

So he creates a murderer. He modifies a small boy's teddy to teach him that killing humans is quite a desirable thing to do.

I cannot remember how it ended. It might be Asimov. I searched through the titles of all his short stories but saw nothing that obviously fitted.

Maybe the title was something like Always Listen to Teddy.

I read it in the 80s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [*I Always Do What Teddy Says*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?62854) by Harry Harrison.

[This review](https://openpublishing.psu.edu/utopia/content/i-always-do-what-teddy-says) seems a likely match

> Teddy bear robots are used to socialize and educate small children. One is tampered with to allow the person to kill a political enemy

Comment: Damn, gotta learn not to stop and dig up quotes. ;-P

Comment: Thanks anyway 